# How to check if the snapshot is now 'completed'

Tags: python, boto3

i am using boto3 to create snapshot of a id and i just need to check if the snapshot is finished creating , but the following loop doesn't do that and just runs to infinity .

```
regions = ['eu-central-1']
for region in regions:
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, )
    snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-f9e7d220', Description='fra01-he-trial-ansible01')
    print snapshot.id

    get_all_snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(snap_id=['SnapshotIds'])
    print get_all_snapshots

    while snapshot.state != 'completed':
          ## put a condition here to get all snapshot or update the state !
          print snapshot.progress
          print "Snapshot under creation"
          time.sleep(10)
    else:
        print "snapshot READY"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [`snapshot.load()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.load) before the loop and after your `sleep` statement.

Just tested it on an AWS micro instance and it works when added to your code.

```
snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-#####', Description='snapshotID')
print snapshot.id
snapshot.load()
while snapshot.state != 'completed':
      print snapshot.progress
      print "Snapshot under creation"
      time.sleep(10)
      snapshot.load()
else:
    print "snapshot READY"
```

Answer (score 4):

Maximillian brings up `load`, but I recommend you use the [waiter](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.SnapshotCompleted). This will handle all the waiting logic for you and return when your snapshot is completed. For that resource, you would use: [`snapshot.wait_until_completed()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.wait_until_completed).

In general, using a waiter (when available) is preferable over custom waiting logic because they handle all the edge cases and other implementation details. For instance, if there is an error in the snapshot creation process, it will enter the `error` state. The code in the accepted answer will continue polling until the resource is completely gone, at which point it will raise an error. This could take very a long time. The waiter will poll a maximum of 40 times in this case, with a retry delay of 15 seconds. (You can see the definition [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/data/ec2/2016-04-01/waiters-2.json#L382).) So instead of waiting several hours or days, you will only wait a maximum of 10 minutes. Different waiters have different retry delays and max numbers of retries. Many waiters have additional information about unrecoverable states, and will fail fast in those cases.

Comment: Thanks for the additional solution! What are the possible edge cases?

Comment: For some APIs, the resource can go into several different states which may or may not reflect failure. The resource may stay in that state for some time. The waiters know what states are unrecoverable, and will fail fast in those cases.

For instance, if there is an error in the snapshot creation process, it will enter the `error` state. The code in the accepted answer will continue polling until the resource is completely gone, at which point it will raise an error. This could take a long time. Updating my answer to include this.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Thanks Jordon for this solution

Comment: @JordonPhillips I tried with this  -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218141/snapshot-wait-until-completed-doesnt-show-progress-nor-when-it-has-completed

Answer (score 1):

## Using Waiter with your own timeout control

Default timeout is 600 seconds (delay=15 seconds x max_attempts=40) as stated in the [Boto3 EC2.Waiter.SnapshotCompleted](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.SnapshotCompleted).

> Polls EC2.Client.describe_snapshots() every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

To verify the current settings of the waiter:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> waiter=client.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
>>> print waiter.config.__dict__
{'delay': 15, '_config': OrderedDict([(u'delay', 15), (u'operation', u'DescribeSnapshots'), (u'maxAttempts', 40), (u'acceptors', [OrderedDict([(u'expected', u'completed'), (u'matcher', u'pathAll'), (u'state', u'success'), (u'argument', u'Snapshots[].State')])])]), 'description': '', 'operation': u'DescribeSnapshots', 'max_attempts': 40}
```

Use Waiter with your own time out:

```
delay= 15
max_attempts = 80
def wait_snapshot(ec2, snapshot):
    waiter = ec2.meta.client.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')

    # Set the timeout
    # Waiter timeout is 10 min (Boto default is delay=15 * max_attempts=40).
    waiter.config.delay = delay
    waiter.config.max_attempts = max_attempts
    waiter.wait(
        SnapshotIds=[
            snapshot.id
        ],
    )
```