# snapshot.wait_until_completed doesn't show progress nor when it has completed

Tags: python, boto3

I have a small function which is responsible for creating the snapshots , it works fine; but i want to get the progress as well , but the following function doesn't help me:

```
def call_creater():
    regions = ['eu-central-1']
    for region in regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, )
        snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-f9e7d220', Description='fra01-he-trial-ansible01')
        print snapshot.id

        get_all_snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(snap_id=['SnapshotIds'])
        print get_all_snapshots
        #snapshot.wait_until_completed()
        print "STARTING TO CREATE :"
        time.sleep(10)
        snapshot.wait_until_completed(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'progress'
                }
                ]
        )
        print "snapshot ready"
```

This throws :

```
    'Name': 'progress'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 368, in do_waiter
    waiter(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 201, in __call__
    response = waiter.wait(**params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 53, in wait
    Waiter.wait(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 321, in wait
    reason='Max attempts exceeded')
botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter SnapshotCompleted failed: Max attempts exceeded
```

Though the snapshot gets created , i am not able to get the status

Answer (score 3):

[`wait_until_completed` should wait for a maximum of about 10 minutes](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.wait_until_completed), which is nowhere near enough for a big snapshot, and [reportedly it's returning faster even than that](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/705). Since this functionality seems to be broken I'd suggest writing your own waiter.

Comment: does the load() sounds better with a while loop which checks for the state of snapshot

Comment: I don't know `load`, but a function which takes another function, a timeout and an interval between checks is a very common pattern in my experience.